# SPRESENSEでattachTimerInterrupt()でピン割り込みをできたが、その後停止したい。

Tags: c++, c, spresense, arduino

SPRESENSEを用いてGPS情報を取得中に時間がかかるので取得中にボタンを押下することで、停止するようなプログラムを作成しています。
ですが、その処理を終わった後はボタンを別の処理に使いたいのでdetachInterrupt(pin)で割り込み機能を停止したいと思っているのですが、arduino dueでしか使えないとあります。

SPRESENSEで利用できるようなものは何かありますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: タイトルは「ピン割り込みのattachInterrupt()」の誤記でしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ピン割り込みの`attachInterrupt()`については、`detachInterrupt()`で解除できますし、

```c
void attachInterrupt(uint8_t interrupt, void (*isr)(void), int mode);
void detachInterrupt(uint8_t interrupt);
```

timer割り込みの`attachTimerInterrupt()`に対しては、`detachTimerInterrupt()`で解除できると思います。

```c
void attachTimerInterrupt(unsigned int (*isr)(void), unsigned int us);
void detachTimerInterrupt(void);
```

Comment: 普通に使えるんですね！ありがとうございます。